# Why active directory is accessible on port 389 even after SSL is enabled?

Tags: c#, ssl, active-directory

I basically have three questions here: I need to use .Net 3.5.

1. I have enabled SSL on my active directory. I have exported the certificate and imported on a different machine. Now when I try to access the active directory using port 389, it allows me to connect . Is this an expected behavior?
2. Many places I found to use "LDAPS" in my directory path when using SSL. But when I use this I get Unknown COM Exception. Here on MSDN I found there is nothing such "LDAPS"
   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/723c3908-5806-4515-a5b2-b565e0131a2b/active-directory-connection-ldap-over-ssl
3. Do I really need to provide the domain name before username (domain\user)? I am able to connect without specifying the domain name this way. All I need to provide the FQDN or the name to which the SSL certificate is issued.

I am using DirectoryEntry class for my implementation.

```
string path = "LDAP://hostname:port/SearchBase";
DirectoryEntry _directoryEntryObj = new DirectoryEntry(path, userName, password);
if(IsSSL)
    _directoryEntryObj.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;
object obj = _directoryEntryObj.NativeObject;
```

Comment: "I need to use c# 3.5" - well that's unfortunate, because that doesn't exist :( But good news! .NET 3.5 exists!

Comment: Edited, sorry being like that ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't deactivate plain LDAP, it is an expected behavior, since LDAPS uses a different port, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol

In general I don't believe you will get far with an AD that only runs on LDAPS (port 636), with plain LDAP (389) blocked. I don't think that most appliations implement LDAPS, but I could be wrong.

On top, the certificate has to valid. If you just export to another machine (with another hostname), the certificate won't be trusted. What kind of certificate do you use?

2. this could be linked with my concern regarding the validity of your certificate
3. When I played around with ldap/ad in .Net I found that you can also just use the current user. If you don't want to use that user, you'll have to go with domain\user. I also think that you consider that best practice, since you can always determine if the specified user is a local account or a domain account.

--

Hope I could help,
regards

Comment: I am using a certificate generated by Microsoft Cirtification Authority on Windows Server 2008 R2. This is issues with th FQDN of the machine on which it is created.
Again the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) says about 'ldaps' while the link in my question says there is nothing such as 'ldaps', this is just a notation to represent ssl over ldap